# Which part of speech are 's' and 'r' in Wordnet?

Tags: computational-linguistics, nlp, online-resources, computer-science, wordnet

From taking the synset of the word 'fantastic', I got a list of senses below:

[Synset('antic.**s**.01'), Synset('fantastic.**s**.02'), Synset('fantastic.**s**.03'), Synset('fantastic.**s**.04'), Synset('fantastic.**s**.05')]

What does '**s**' stand for?

Another example, taking a synset of the word 'fast':

[Synset('fast.**n**.01'), Synset('fast.**v**.01'), Synset('fast.**v**.02'), Synset('fast.**a**.01'), Synset('fast.**a**.02'), Synset('fast.**a**.03'), Synset('fast.**s**.04'), Synset('fast.**s**.05'), Synset('debauched.**s**.01'), Synset('flying.**s**.02'), Synset('fast.**s**.08'), Synset('firm.**s**.10'), Synset('fast.**s**.10'), Synset('fast.**r**.01'), Synset('fast.**r**.02')]

Again what does '**s**' stand for? And also what does '**r**' stand for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the [NLTK documentation](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html?highlight=wordnet#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Lemma.synset) is a bit off. Looking at [Wordnet's documents](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wndb.5WN.html), I see:

> pos
>
> Syntactic category: n for noun files, v for verb files, a for adjective files, r for adverb files.

And in another section of the same document:

> ss_type
>
> One character code indicating the synset type:
>
> n    NOUN
>
> v    VERB
>
> a    ADJECTIVE
>
> s    ADJECTIVE SATELLITE
>
> r    ADVERB

Comment: Is 'adjective satellite' a term used in any linguistic theories, or is it something Wordnet made up themselves?

Comment: @curiousdannii: I'm afraid I don't know offhand.

Comment: @curiousdannii - adjective satellite is something Wordnet came up with - it refers to adjectives that always occur in instances relating to some other object - the canonical example is "atomic bomb".